# Run two thread groups at a same time in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have two independent threads in Jmeter.How to run both the threads at a Single run?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you create two thread groups, by default jmeter will run them concurrently.

Comment: if you're here trying to fix this issue, then:  Watch out for the "Run Thread Groups consecutively" toggle being checked (on the TestPlan 'root page'), which will inhibit this default